# How to unvote great comment?

Tags: feature-request

I have accidentally clicked on "this is a great comment" arrow. But I can't find any way how to undo this (it was unwanted click).

Is there some way? If there isn't, can I ask why? If so, can it be added to the system (at least for such cases - accident)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As a general rule, you should check the main [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) before asking a question here. :) They have been asked nearly everything possible...

In this case, the answer to [Can I undo a comment upvote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment) is:

> - You can un-upvote a comment **within the first 60 seconds**, provided you did not navigate away.
> - Once you un-upvote a comment you can not upvote it again.

Comment: Not only the correct information, but a good practice to follow.

Answer (score 3):

you can simply click on that arrow again, it will ask you if you want to undo the upvote. but later you can not upvote that comment again.

Comment: Worked for me! And I could also not add the upvote again, as you said. It gives me a message: "You already upvoted this comment in the past and undid the vote, you can not upvote it again"

Comment: Not working for me. I can click arrow as many as I want, but nothing happens. I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: @zacharmarz I'm using chrome too, so i'm not sure what is causing that problem.